# want 2nd highest salary order by department wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create table #t 
(id int,
deptid int,
sal int)

insert into #t values (1,1,1000),(2,1,2000),(3,1,3000),(4,2,2000),(5,2,3000),(6,2,6000)

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Expected output :

```
id            deptid   sal
2              1              2000
5              2              3000
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over(partition by deptid order by sal desc) as rn
from #t)

select *
from cte
where rn = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ID, deptid, sal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY deptid ORDER BY deptid) SR FROM #t
)

SELECT ID, deptid, sal FROM CTE WHERE SR = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your required query

```
create table #t 
(id int,
deptid int,
sal int)

insert into #t values (1,1,1000),(2,1,2000),(3,1,3000),(4,2,2000),(5,2,3000),(6,2,6000)

select * from (
SELECT id,deptid,sal,row_number() over(partition by deptid order by sal)rnum FROM #t
) as a
where rnum=2
```